# How to get value from Django authentication forms and use that value as input to another form?

Tags: python, django, forms, python-2.7, forms-authentication

I have a form used to create new posts in a blog, and one of the fields in that form is the owner, which means who is posting it, but that should be taken from login view when user provides his/her login information I don't want the user selecting who is the owner from a list, it should be automatically populated and fixed with his username. I tried different ways, fixing the value on my forms.py but didn't work, it doesn't recognizes the variable. This is my forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('website', 'picture')


class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body','datposted', 'category','owner')
```

Here is what I have on models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    datposted = models.DateTimeField('date posted')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title
```

This is my view:

```
def create_post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.datposted = datetime.datetime.now()
        #post.owner = request.user()
        post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Favor. Verifique os campos necessarios")

else:
    form = CreatePostForm()
    f = {'form' : form}
    return render(request,'create_post.html',f)
```

Could you please help with more details?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to remove the 'owner' field from the form and make sure that you  handle populating the owner in your view

```
class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body','datposted', 'category')
```

## view

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            Posts = form.save(commit=False) 
            # replace below with however you get user profile
            Posts.owner = get_user_profile_from_logged_in_user()
            Posts.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Favor. Verifique os campos necessarios")

    else:
        form = CreatePostForm()
        f = {'form' : form}
        return render(request,'create_post.html',f)
```

This case is covered in django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: It seems to be the right way, but now i got the following error:

ValueError
Exception Value:  

Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: marlm123>>": "Post.owner" must be a "UserProfile" instance.

Comment: @MarceloMoraes replace line with howerver userprofile is linked to the current logged in user

Comment: Sorry, I had model Posts earlier, renamed recently.....I fixed that, and got this:
unbound method save() must be called with Post instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: I may not understood exactly what is needed. Would it help if I edit my question and add some other code ? Let me know. 
I didn't understand when you say "howerver userprofile is linked to the current logged in user"

Comment: could you please tell me more details on what you meant in your previous comment ? If you can use my view as example would help a lot